# Is using the visually hidden technique better than img alt text?

Tags: html, accessibility

I'm curious whether the CSS visually-hidden technique, most commonly used on font icons, for alternative image text is preferable to using the alt attribute. The argument against the alt attribute being that a screen reader announces "Graphic" any time it sees and `<img>` which is less natural. For example:

```html
<p>ABC <img src="right-arrow.png" src="converts to"> XYZ</p>
```

Reads as "ABC graphic converts to XYZ"

```html
<p>
  ABC
  <span class="visually-hidden">converts to</span>
  <img src="right-arrow.png" src="" aria-hidden="true">
  XYZ
</p>
```

Reads as "ABC converts to XYZ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can agree it's less natural when screen reader reads "Graphic" every time we focus on some image. From the other hand, straightforward explanation of type of content may be extremely important for people with impairments. Navigating through site is hard enough, so if we can narrow the field of interpretation, it's advised to do it.

What I mean is surfing the Internet with screen reader is not a perfect experience. But for the moment we have to stick to it and by making some things more schematic, we actually make it a little more clearer.

Also we can look to [WCAG docs about this issue](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/quickref/?versions=2.0&showtechniques=111#text-alternatives) where there's a few advised techniques to choose from.

> Situation A: If a short description can serve the same purpose and present the same information as the non-text content:
>   G94: Providing short text alternative for non-text content that serves the same purpose and presents the same information as the non-text content using one of the following techniques:
>   Short text alternative techniques for Situation A:
>
> ARIA6: Using aria-label to provide labels for objects
>
> ARIA10: Using aria-labelledby to provide a text alternative for non-text content
>
> G196: Using a text alternative on one item within a group of images that describes all items in the group
>
> H2: Combining adjacent image and text links for the same resource
>
> H35: Providing text alternatives on applet elements
>
> H37: Using alt attributes on img elements
>
> H53: Using the body of the object element
>
> H86: Providing text alternatives for ASCII art, emoticons, and leetspeak

So basically we could choose also from aria-attributes (and we can sometimes, but only if alt is not enough) BUT there is also one more strong argument for using `alt` attributes - ***SEO***
Using alt text on your images can make for a better user experience, but it may also help earn you both explicit and implicit SEO benefits. Along with implementing image title and file naming best practices, including alt text may also contribute to image SEO.

> While search engine image recognition technology has vastly improved over the years, search crawlers still can't "see" the images on a website page like we can, so it's not wise to leave the interpretation solely in their hands. If they don't understand, or get it wrong, it's possible you could either rank for unintended keywords or miss out on ranking altogether.

[quote from here](https://moz.com/learn/seo/alt-text)

Comment: Interesting [H2: Combining adjacent image and text links for the same resource](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/html/H2.html) is basically the solution used except we are hiding the text visually.

"making some things more schematic" is not and angle i thought of.

SEO is not important here (web app) but good to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

**Both techniques are counterproductive and useless.**

In your example :

> ABC → XYZ

This means nothing to me. I'm not blind, I have no screenreader. And I still don't understand what is this curious arrow.

Of course having an `img` tag (with an `alt`) may help me to understand the meaning of this arrow by hovering with a mouse. But, how can I guess that this arrow is in fact an `img` tag and that I have to hover with my mouse? How can I do without using a mouse?

Let's try another method :

> ABC converts to XYZ

We don't use `img` tag, we don't use visually hidden text. Everybody with or without screenreader will understand.

There are a lot more people targeted by accessibility than blind people and you should always try to satisfy everybody.

Comment: I think the arrow would make sense within the larger context of the design. This is just pseudo code, a quick example i could whip up, that illustrates the gist of the problem without getting to far into the weeds.

Comment: @blg002 Yes, of course, this illustrates the problem. But the same thing will happen with any image / symbol :  if it requires an explanation, everybody needs that explanation

Comment: Interesting! I think what you're advocating for is an explicit definition for iconography (and other things?). I question at what point can we relay on a colloquial understanding of things? Possibly never? A solution to your issue may also be adding title attr for the sighted. However, this has really gotten away from the main question i had.